# Hash with multiple values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following input .txt file:

```
FROM       TO
London     Paris
London     NYC
NYC        Cairo
Cairo      Rome
London     Paris
```

and I need to get all the unique destinations TOs

```
"London" -> ["Paris", "NYC"]
"NYC" -> ["Cairo]
"Cairo" -> ["Rome"]
```

so that I can compare them with another array of strings that looks like this A = ["Vienna", "Luxembourg", "Rome"].

This solution does not work.

```
 h = Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key]}
 lineCounter = 0
 file = File.open(arcFile2,"r")
 Line = file.first.split(" ")
 file.each_line do |line|
  if lineCounter == 0 then
  lineCounter = lineCounter + 1
  elsif lineCounter > 0 then
  Line = line.split("\t")
  from = Line[firstLine.index "from"].to_s.chomp
  to = Line[firstLine.index "to"].to_s.chomp
  h[from] = to
 end
end
puts h["London"] & A
```

EDIT: The code works when I define my hash as following:

```
h = Hash.new{|hash, key| hash[key] = Array.new}
h[from].push to
```

The question is now how do I add unique values because in this case I will have

```
"London" -> ["Paris", "NYC", "Paris"]
```

Comment: What aspect of it doesn't work?

Comment: @splrs I don't know how to add an array to a hash key because this one gives replaces the values s.t. "London" will only have the last value and in this case it is "Paris"

Answer (score 0):

```
File.open(file).each_line.drop(1)
.map(&:split)
.group_by(&:first)
.map{|k, v| [k, v.map(&:last).uniq]}
# => [
  ["London", ["Paris", "NYC"]],
  ["NYC", ["Cairo"]],
  ["Cairo", ["Rome"]]
]
```

In Ruby 2.4:

```
File.open(file).each_line.drop(1)
.map(&:split)
.group_by(&:first)
.transform_values{|v| v.map(&:last).uniq}
# => {
  "London" => ["Paris", "NYC"],
  "NYC" => ["Cairo"],
  "Cairo" => ["Rome"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your updated question:

> The question is now how do I add unique values?

You can use `none?`, something like this:

```
h[from].push(to) if h[from].none? { |i| i == to }
```

Also consider using a set (which contains only unique elements) instead of an array:

```
require 'set'

set = Set.new ['a','b']
#=> #<Set: {"a", "b"}>
set << 'a'
#=> #<Set: {"a", "b"}>
```